# I keep getting segfault 11 on the second if loop, what's the reason?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that reads a person name on the form first name followed by either middle name and last name or just last name. Then the program should display the name as last name followed by comma, then first letter of the first name followed by a period. Example of input:

```
John Smith
```

the output should be

```
Smith J.
```

Another example input:

```
John David Smith
```

output:

```
Smith D. J.
```

This is the program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char space[2] = " ";

int main(){
    char input[50], firstName[20], middleName[20], lastName[20], *token;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &input);
    token = strtok(input, space);
    strcpy(firstName, token);   
    if (token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
        strcpy(middleName, token);
    }
    if (token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
        strcpy(lastName, token);
        printf("%s %c. %c.\n", lastName, middleName[0], firstName[0]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", middleName);
        printf("%s %c.\n", middleName, firstName[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works when the input name has a middle name, for example if I type "John David Smith" it will throw "Smith D. J.", but if I type "John Smith", it will throw a segfault 11. 
    So what's the problem? Is is because I didn't use strtok properly?

Comment: You need to check if `strtok()` returns NULL in *every* call. In both of the `if` statements, you don't check that.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You are testing for a `NULL` value for `token` **after** using it as an argument to `strcpy`: you are effectively invoking undefined behavior unless all 3 parts are present.
- You pass the address of the array `input` as the destination for `scanf("%[\n]"`.  This is incorrect, although unlikely to cause a problem.
- There is an extra `s` at the end of the `"%[\n]"` format.  Incorrect but not a major issue.
- You do not check the return value of `scanf()`.  If the input is empty, your code invokes undefined behavior.
- You do not provide `scanf` with size information to prevent buffer overflow on invalid input.
- The arrays for `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName` are smaller than `intput`.  You may cause buffer overflows on input with very long name parts.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char space[2] = " ";

int main(void) {
    char input[50], firstName[50], middleName[50], lastName[50], *token;

    if (scanf("%49[^\n]", input) != 1)
        return 1;
    token = strtok(input, space);
    if (token != NULL) {
        strcpy(firstName, token);   
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
        if (token != NULL) {
            strcpy(middleName, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, space);
            if (token != NULL) {
                strcpy(lastName, token);
                printf("%s %c. %c.\n", lastName, middleName[0], firstName[0]);
            } else {
                printf("%s %c.\n", middleName, firstName[0]);
            }
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", firstName);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you do not need to copy the name parts, `strtok()` returns pointers to the `input` array that remain valid after successive calls as long as `input` remains in scope.  Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char space[2] = " ";

int main(void) {
    char input[50], *part1, *part2, *part3;

    if (scanf("%49[^\n]", input) != 1)
        return 1;

    part1 = strtok(input, space);
    if (part1 != NULL) {
        part2 = strtok(NULL, space);
        if (part2 != NULL) {
            part3 = strtok(NULL, space);
            if (part3 != NULL) {
                printf("%s %c. %c.\n", part3, *part1, *part2);
            } else {
                printf("%s %c.\n", part2, *part1);
            }
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", part1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a slight addition for completeness, "`strtok()` returns pointers to the `input` array that remain valid after successive calls"... *so long as `input` remains in scope*.

Comment: @Zhou: can you please accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` expects a `char *` but you pass a `char **`.  In practice, these will typically evaluate to the same value, so this is most likely not the cause of the segfault.
2. You check `token` for `NULL` **before** reading the next token instead of after.  So if you do the check, then call `strtok` again which returns `NULL`, then use `token`, you dereference a `NULL` pointer.

So make the following updates:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", input);     // pass input, not &input
token = strtok(input, space);
strcpy(firstName, token);
token = strtok(NULL, space);     // get token first
if (token != NULL){
    strcpy(middleName, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, space);     // get token first
}
if (token != NULL){
    strcpy(lastName, token);
    printf("%s %c. %c.\n", lastName, middleName[0], firstName[0]);
}
else {
    printf("%s", middleName);
    printf("%s %c.\n", middleName, firstName[0]);
}
```